# Direct upload to S3 from download

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I am using an API to download a file which I then want to upload to S3.  Currently I am saving the file in the tmp directory and then uploading it to S3 from there.

What I want to achieve is a direct upload to s3 from calling the service.

The API call returns a HTTParty::Response and I am using Heroku.

Comment: what have you done so far to solve this ?

Comment: Like I said the only thing I have done so far is save it to a temp file and then upload it.  I have not managed to find anything on this in the aws-sdk documentation or anywhere else.  So I'm not sure if it is possible.

Comment: S3 will not download files from remote locations. You have to "push" the file to S3. Downloading to a tmp folder is pretty much your only option.